# Python regex search fails despite match

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I’ve read questions on re.search issues but nothing is working. I have a list called cols, and an arg from Argparse. searchstring is definitely found in cols[8]

```
cols = []
```

Then later in the code:

```
cols = line.split(‘\t’)
searchstring = args.attribute + ‘’ + args.value
# ...
re.search(searchstring, cols[8])
```

Comment: Hi lizam, welcome to Stack Overflow. We are going to need some more information! Can you please give us concrete examples of what you are trying to find, what your regex is, and what the expected vs. actual outcome is?

Comment: Try debugging the code by printing cols[8] before using re.search. If cols[8] is printed properly, there is definitely some error in search string formation. Try printing args.attribute and args.value too and try to observe the searchstring.You might find the error there

Comment: Thanks, the search string wasn’t right which led me to the error. Appreciate it!